# The TLS connection was non-properly terminated - causing mail loop

Tags: ssl, exim

I run an exim4 mailserver, have done for years, but today I've been innundated by another server that keeps resending the same message.

It's a valid message (it's a school newsletter) but it seems that:

1. their mail server sends mail
2. these lines appear in the logs

   ```
   [their_server_ip] (recv): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.                
   [their_server_ip] (send): The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
   ```
3. my mail server delivers the mail to me anyway
4. their server thinks it didn't work and retries and the loop continues.

I've checked my server's TLS is up to date and the certificate is OK with a couple of the usual online SSL checkers.

What could be going on?

Comment: Can you check if ipv6 is enabled, if yes, please disable and test.

Comment: @asktyagi Eh? Why would IPv6 be a problem?

Comment: The remote address redacted in the logs above was an ipv4 one. I don't think I have ipv6 enabled.